# Memory management for "id<ProtocolName> variableName" type properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, properties

I'm having a problem with properties of the following type:

```
id<ProtocolName> variableName;
.....
.....
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ProtocolName> variableName;
```

I can access and use them just fine, but when I try to call

```
[variableName release];
```

I get compiler warnings:

```
'-release' not found in protocol(s)
```

Do I need to define a release method in the interface, or how do I release the memory reserved for the variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your protocol adopts NSObject.

```
@protocol ProtocolName <NSObject>
...
```

Comment: This assumes that you have control over the protocol definition — but if you do, yes, this is a good solution.

Comment: In this case I do have control over the protocol definition - added NSObject and it works perfectly. Thanks! :)

Comment: Just to expand slightly on this.  If a protocol `AProtocol` does not adopt `NSObject` and you receive an object of type `id<AProtocol>` you cannot assume that the object responds to `-retain` and `-release`.  There is nothing in Objective-C that says an object *has* to inherit from `NSObject`.  `NSObject` is not part of the Objective-C language, it is part of the Foundation framework.

Answer (score 3):

`release` is in the NSObject protocol, so you can declare it as `id<ProtocolName, NSObject>` to work within the type system or cast it to a plain `id` to stop its class from being typechecked.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add `NSObject` to the protocol list.